# any idea....fast tool/way to find what was added?

Tags: arithmetic

can anyone please help with a tool or even quicker method?

e.g. If I had 163.78 and wanted to make it 200.00 is there a way to find out what was added to make it 200.00?  (+36.22 in this case)

I need this everyday, and would be greatly appreciated as im not good using my slow manual method.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Subtraction maybe?

Comment: ... Subtraction? And how is this combinatorics?

Comment: is there any quick tool for a one click option?

Comment: where should this be placed?

Comment: If you don't want to do the subtraction by hand, how about using a calculator? Just type 200 - 163.78 into a calculator.

Comment: yes that the way im doing it, but im not that good

Comment: What in the world could be quicker than subtracting?

Comment: If you have to do a large number of subtractions like this, maybe you could write a computer program to do them for you automatically. Otherwise, I don't think anything will be faster than using a calculator (except maybe doing it mentally, with practice).

Comment: ok im thinking if this will always work for me , so simple

Comment: your right , i think thats the way, omg sorry its so basic when you explained it

Comment: thanks you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a calculator to find the answer quickly.

All you have to do enter $200-163.78$ and push enter to get the answe $36.22$
If you do not use calculator then you can get the answer in few steps.

First take $160$ out of $200$ to get $40$

Then take $3$ out of $40$ to get $37$

Then take $0.70$ out of $37$ to get $36.30$ and finally take $0.08$ out of $36.30$ to get $36.22$
It sounds messy but with practice you can do it fast.

Comment: thanks, im all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a computer program for this. For example in Python:

```
print 200.0-163.78
```

Comment: thanks, no worries, i just had a really dumb moment!  i didnt know it was that easy to get the rounded number you want, i used to add it up slowly testing out the guesses, on the calc until i made it! lol so dumb,